# ubuntu:display the amount of free space im megabyte for each partitions in my linux

Tags: unix, ubuntu

i need to display the amount of free space in megabyte for each partitions in my Linux.
   and i need to display free space for whole hard drive.
     but i did not know how.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df -BM` would get you what you want in megabytes

try `df -BM --total` this would be a rough approx, on my ubuntu i have two entries pointing to a same partition so it would have counted that twice

try `df --help` for list of options

and you should post to [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) for ubuntu related questions

Comment: thanks and how to display the amount of free space of the hard drive in megabyte ?

Comment: you have the `Available` column there

Comment: i know display the amount of free space of the whole hard drive in megabyte not for each partitions

Comment: you mean unpartitioned space ? or the sum of free space in all the partitions

Comment: whole free space in hard drive in megabyte

Comment: sum of free space in all the partitions

Comment: try `df -BM --total` this would be a rough approx, on my ubuntu i have two entries pointing to a same partition so it would have counted that twice

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46032/discussion-between-mzzzzb-and-john)

Answer (score 1):

```bash
df -h
```

Will show the amount of use for each partition on your system.

Comment: i need to show the free space?